# How to update runtime scene via the editor

Tags: unreal-engine4

Is it possible to update the' position/rotation of an object in a running game by setting its properties in the editor. In other words, when I change something in Unreal editor I'd like to see it change immediately in a running instance of the game.

Comment: From what I know it's not possible. This would require to store all of the current game state somewhere in the filesys or RAM and then deatach library containing all of your game, then compile it again and attach it to the engine. At last you would have to restore the game state but in that moment it can differ from the original state so it would require additional effort. Based on that I think it's impossible.

Comment: @m.rogalski Editor itself is kind of a playing game and you can edit properties there too. It is possible to change properties during runtime (check my answer).

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich I've always thought that it's not possible due to the fact that this process would be complicated. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: Well, my intention was to run the game in stand-alone mode and modify objects in the editor at while the game is running and reflect those changes in the running game. Pavel's answer unfortunately does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it **is possible**. Steps to do so (tested in 3rd person template, UE 1.17)

1. Play in editor
2. Hit **Shift + F1** to show mouse cursor and unlock from viewport
3. Click on **Eject** button (it is on upper toolbar where *Compile*, *Play* and *Launch* buttons are.
4. Click on mesh on scene and edit it's properties
5. Hit **Posses** button (now instead of Eject)
6. Play in modified world

Be aware that editor will show some warnings if you move Mesh with **Static Mobility**. Also, shadows could be off (especially if you are using pre-built lighting).

*EDIT*: there is another procedure: instead of PIE, you can start **Simulate** (*Alt* + *S*). Then you don't need to do *Unposses* / *Posses* actions, just edit properties. There is a catch - your game needs to be playable in *Simulate* mode. From my experience, due to various reasons I couldn't run one of my game in *Simulate*, so I had to repeat that 6 steps I mentioned earlier.